# Is this system of differential equations homogeneous?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I learned that a system of $k$ differential equations is homogeneous if

\begin{equation}
x_i' = p_{i1}(t)x_i + \cdots + p_{in}(t)x_i + g_i(t), \qquad i = 1, 2, \ldots, k
\end{equation}

has $g_i(t) = 0 \: \forall \: i$ where $t \in I$ and $I$ is some interval on which we want to find a solution.

In my book, there is an example that states that the following system of differential equations is homogeneous:

\begin{align}
\frac{dI}{dt} &= \frac{V}{L}\\
\frac{dV}{dt} &= \frac{I}{C} - \frac{V}{RC}
\end{align}

Unless I'm missing something $g(t)$ for the first equation is $\frac{V}{L}$ (which $\neq 0)$, and $g(t)$ for the second equation is $\frac{I}{C}$ (which also $\neq 0$). Could someone please explain if and why this system is homogeneous?

Answer (score 1):

The system is homogeneous. $V/L$ is not of the form $g(t)$. It is the constant $1/L$ times the unknown function $V$. Similarly, $I/C-V(RC)$ is a linear combination of the unknowns $I$ and $V$.

Comment: Got it. So this system can be written as $dI/dt = 0\times I + 1/L\times V$ and $dV/dt = 1/C \times I - 1/(RC) \times V$. Neither of these has a nonzero constant added to it, so the system is homogeneous.